# Any tips on controlling Catapodium Rigidum (ferngrass)?

Tags: weed-control

I'm on the Bellarine Peninsula in Victoria, Aus, and the last couple of summers this species is becoming more and more prolific in my garden beds and lawns. No matter how much hand weeding I do, I seem to spread it more.
Any suggestions on controlling it, please?
Thanks in advance!

[image: Catapodium Rigidum]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an annual.  I'd suggest a pre-emergent control.

Comment: Thanks for that. Bad case of winter weed too, so hopefully can kill those two birds with the one stone!

Comment: You may have to fight this for a few seasons. Don't know how long the seeds are viable.